# On this question test a categorical syllogism to determine whether it is valid or invalid

Tags: logic

Some songwriters are musicians, because all recording artists are musicians and some recording artists are songwriters.

Answer (score 2):

Write it in "syllogistic form" :

> All recording artists are musicians;
>
> Some recording artists are songwriters.
>
> > Therefore, some songwriters are musicians.

And compare with [Valid syllogistic figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Types).

---

In more "modern" terms :

> assume not, i.e. that there is **no** person that is a Songwriter and a Musician.

By 2nd premise, there is at least one guy - call it Joe - which is a Recording artist and a Songwriter.

But by 1st premise, every Recording artist is also a Musician.

> Thus, Joe is a Songwriter and also a Musician.

*Contradiction !*

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this please

Comment: HOw to accept the answer as new here

Comment: Could you help me on this one too 
All ranchers who own large estates are people who own guns, therefore All people who hunt are people who own guns, since All ranchers who own large estates are people who hunt.

Comment: could you help me on this one too ......

All ranchers who own large estates are people who own guns, therefore All people who hunt are people who own guns, since All ranchers who own large estates are people who hunt.

Comment: @SteveMarker You really shouldn't be asking new questions in the comments ... but it sounds like a good opportunity to try a Venn diagram! :)

Comment: Ohh my bad I thought you and Mauro helped me on the first question so I did posted but since new to this site as my friend told me about this one .

Comment: @SteveMarker No problem; I know you're new! :) How's that Venn diagram coming along?

Comment: I have opened few pages and trying to study how the Venn diagram works I have just started the classes so trying to solve some easy one's but these 2 questions are difficult that's why needed some help.

Comment: Will you be able to help me on my second question too ..:)

Comment: @SteveMarker I encourage you to ask a new question for this new problem, and in that question show your attempt at the Venn diagram ... in Paint you can create these diagrams pretty quickly (use the 'Fill' feature for 'shading'), and you can insert the pictures into your post like I did.

Answer (score 2):

Venn diagrams are a great tool to evaluate Categorical Syllogisms!

First, draw the basic Venn diagram involving the three categories:

[image]

Now, let's incorporate the information of the first premise:

> "All Recording artists are musicians"

To do this, we will shade out the area that is inside the Recording Artists, but outside Musicians: that will force any recording artists to indeed be a musician:

[image]

Then, take the second premise:

> "Some recording artists are songwriters"

To express that information, we put an 'X' in the intersection of Recording Artists and Songwriters, and due to the earlier shading there is only one area left where this can be:

[image]

No, we look at our conclusion:

> "Some songwriters are musicians"

Now, we do *not* diagram this information into the diagram, but rather *inspect* the diagram (which visually expresseses the information contained within the premises) to see if the diagram will force the conclusion to be true .... and indeed it does! That is, we used the 'X' to represent 'something that is both a Recording Artists  and a Siongwriter, but since it was forced to be in the region that is also inside the Musicians are, the 'X' therefore became something that is all three. And thus, in particular, we know that there has to be something that is both a songwriter and  a musicians, making the conclusion true.

So, since the conclusion was forced to be true if we assumed the premises to be true, we know the argument is valid.

Comment: @SteveMarker You're welcome! Yes, they're pretty cool. Make sure to accept Mauro's answer though!

Answer (score 1):

> Some songwriters are musicians, because all recording artists are
>   musicians and some recording artists are songwriters.

1. All recording artists are musicians. (All M are P)
2. Some recording artists are songwriters. (Some M are S)

Conclusion: Some songwriters are musicians. (Some S are P)

The syllogism is Form AII in the third figure, and is valid.